# Доказать NP за время 2^(O(n^k))

Tags: алгоритм

Друзья, подскажите, как решается вот такое задание с курса по анализу алгоритмов.
Докажите, что любая задача класса NP может быть решена за время 2^(O(n^k)) для какой-либо константы k.

Comment: все NP полные задачи имеют одинаковую сложность (упрощённо). Берём любую, она решается за O(2 ^n) ну и сойдёт =)

Comment: NP или NP-полная? Может, исходить из того, что проверить один ответ можно за полиномиальное время (поскольку NP), так что если перебрать все ответы и проверить каждый, то нужный найдем?

Comment: В задании речь именно об NP. Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Если просто NP, то, возможно, годятся мои рассуждения. Если NP-полная, то как у @pavel.